# how to mount raid

Tags: raid

I have the following funny experiment. 
I used a live usb to install ubuntu server 12.04 i386 and webmin on a usb plugged to an intel ss4200-e, i would like to make a headless samba server out of it.
webmin shows the following situation on the partitions menu:

```
Disk name       Total size      Make and model      Partitions      Actions   
SCSI device A   7.39 GB     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0   3   Identify drive
SATA device B   953.83 GB   ATA Hitachi HDE72101    1   IDE parameters | Identify drive
SATA device C   953.83 GB   ATA Hitachi HDE72101    1   IDE parameters | Identify drive
SATA device D   953.83 GB   ATA Hitachi HDE72101    1   IDE parameters | Identify drive
SATA device E   953.83 GB   ATA Hitachi HDE72101    1   IDE parameters | Identify drive
```

the raid menu shows:

```
Device name     Status  RAID level  Usable size     Member disk devices
/dev/md0    clean   RAID5 (Distributed Parity)  2.60 TB     /dev/sdb1 | /dev/sdc1 | /dev/sdd1 | /dev/sde1
```

and then the \dev\md0 tab shows

```
Device file     /dev/md0
UUID    fcf48163:7efca14a:7bb08b15:81161d20
RAID level  RAID5 (Distributed Parity)
Filesystem status   Used in LVM VG volume
Usable size     2794526208 blocks (2.60 TB)
Persistent superblock?  Yes
Layout  left-symmetric
Chunk size  128 kB
RAID status     clean
Partitions in RAID  SATA device B partition 1
SATA device C partition 1
SATA device D partition 1
SATA device E partition 1
```

fstab looks like this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=437ea85c-1a1a-449f-a87f-e358cce2ba7e /               ext2    errors=remount                                                           -ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=8800da26-a98b-4a6b-aa96-917fc529bfe1 none            swap    sw                                                                         0       0
```

pvs

```
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/md0   volume lvm2 a-   2,60t    0
```

how do I mount that /dev/md0 into /mnt/raidarray at boot for example?

Comment: Did you format the /dev/md0?

Comment: Since it says `Filesystem status   Used in LVM VG volume` you might want to add the output of `sudo pvs`

Comment: @jawtheshark, I did as ext2, and if I give: sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/raidarray gives an error mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

Comment: Ah, frankly, I rarely use /dev/md0 "bare" and in this case it's set as being an LVM2_member.   For some reason it's part of an lvm.  Try removing it from the lvm.  `sudo pvremove /dev/md0`.

Comment: Considering PFree is 0... You might need to remove all volumes first, then all volume groups and then only you can remove the physical volumes from the LVM.   Did you recycle these disks from somewhere that might have had all this comfigured somehow?

Comment: yes, it's all very old and recycled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your block device  `/dev/md0` is formatted, you issue the following command:

`sudo blkid /dev/md0`

This will give you a UUID and normally will tell you what filesystem it is formatted in.

Then add the following line to your `/etc/fstab`

`UUID=the-uui-blkid-gave-you  /mnt/raidarray file-system-you-used defaults 0 0`

Afterwards type `sudo mount -a` and your device should get mounted.  Do note that the directory `/mnt/raidarray` should exist.

Comment: Thank you. I had to restart from scratch following http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Linux_RAID and then it mounted with your instructions. So I should have asked how to get rid of the "unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'" message ^_^